# overload operator & to produce sum of int[][]

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

it's a test from some company.

overload & to return sum of int[][]

```
main()
{
    int arr[5][5];
    // initialization
    cout << &arr; // output the sum of arr
}
```

I try this code but returns compile error:

```
long operator &(int** arr)
{
    // return the sum of arr
}
```

error: the argument should contains class type or enumeration
currently I understand this error, but how to overload operator for buildin types?

Comment: That aside, an array is not a pointer. `int[5][5]` will not convert to an `int**` because a pointer to an array is not a pointer to an int.

Comment: As the error message says, you can't overload operators for built-in types.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1 -- yes, you can overload the unary `&` operator for user-defined types.

Comment: Yes you can overload, see below

Comment: Well golly, I stand corrected!  (I've deleted my incorrect comment.)

Comment: @Eljay no problem, that's what I like here to learn from each other :)

Answer (score 6):

Example of overloading operator &, only for educational use!
I would NOT recommend overloading operator& in any serious code.

```
#include <iostream>

struct my_array
{
    my_array()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                values[i][j] = 1 + i + j;
            }
        }
    }

    int operator&()
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j)
            {
                sum += values[i][j];
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }

private:
    int values[5][5]{};
};


int main()
{
    my_array m;
    int sum = &m;
    std::cout << sum;
}
```

Comment: I don't know if the question would allow replacing `arr`'s type with a user-defined type. Upvoted anyway, this is probably the closest you can get without using something like the preprocessor to do horrible confusing things (the question itself is IMO a wierd/bad one).

Comment: Question was indeed a bit weird, but looked to me like he was really trying to understand something. And on top of that 'c' style arrays are hard to use in a c++ environment anyway. (No constructors, no destructors, no move semantics and everything RAII i normally use)

Comment: Also by putting the overload in a struct/class any "leakage" of the overload into other code is reduced. Not all int** are guaranteed to be int[5][5].

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying anything about OP's question, it seems to me like this was some interview question (_it's a test from some company_). I don't think that's a very good interview question, or at least a pretty weird one. Come to think of it now, I think you could overload `<<` for `int (*)[5][5]`, but in real life that's something you would really not want to do and is a bad example of operator overloading (Speak of the devil, a new answer was just posted which did that!).

Comment: Maybe that's the best answer you can give, if you want me to overload operator & then I will say it is a bad idea ;) The side effects somewhere else in the code may be really unexpected! Anyway making the example was good fun. Good luck with your interviews!

Comment: cannot change the code of main method, which means it's not possible to use user defined class.

Answer (score 3):

I think interviewer may want you to overload `operator<<` actually, not `&` and the solution could then be like below. See it live [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Hrw5LR9dKhEPV5yr).

```
#include <iostream>

using int5x5_t = int[5][5];

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const int5x5_t* parr) {
  long sum = 0;
  for (auto& vec : *parr) {
    for (auto val : vec) {
      sum += val;
    }
  }
  return os << sum;
}

int main() {
  int arr[5][5] = {
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
    {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
  };
  std::cout << &arr << std::endl;
}
```